# Uploading table (shape) to asset using Google Earth Engine?

Tags: performance, table, google-earth-engine

I am trying to upload a table (shape) to my assets and it has been uploading for 7 days.

Is it normal?

I do not understand why spends so many time.

Answer (score 2):

7 days for a table upload is not normal.

Note that [GIS StackExchange recommends](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) that bug reports and enhancement requests for specific software to be directed to the software development team. See the Earth Engine documentation's [Get Help](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/help) page for a list of support resources.

Answer (score -1):

Does not sound correct.

I would try reuploading it.